# Endless ArrayObject's iterator

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I am iterating an `ArrayObject` inside of the object itself. Lets see:

```
class EventsBag extends ArrayObject{

    public function toJson(){
        $events = [];
        $iterator = $this->getIterator();

        while ($iterator->valid()){
            $events[] = $iterator->current();
            $iterator->next();
        }

        return $events;
    }
}
```

Calling `toJson()` never ends the script execution:

```
$events = new EventsBag(['a', 'b']);
var_dump($events->toJson());
```

I have debugged the script, and the `while` control never get out. I do not get why this happends.

Comment: Perhaps because there's a typo at `$iterator->currect`. (See here for [displaying PHP errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)).

Comment: Hello @Kenney. Typos may occurred in the transcription, but that is not the case.

Comment: Works fine here - https://3v4l.org/mXqHi. Is this your actual code, or just an abstract/filtered code block?

Comment: @Sean, I have just filtered 3 lines decorating printing some values, but this code is not running in my machine. I have seen yours and surprise me that the same lines works for you.